# Fetching URLs via JS resulting in empty files

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch-api

All I want to do is have a nice and simple function that'll take an url and save it to a file, however every single implementation me or some JS developer friends have been able to come up with throughout the day gives the same end result: **an empty file**.

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as path from 'path';
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
import { Headers } from 'node-fetch';

export function downloadURL(url, saveLocation) {
    const absSaveLocation = path.resolve(saveLocation);

    const myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append('User-Agent', 'hifumi-js:v1.0.0');

    if (url.includes("pximg")) {
      myHeaders.append('Referer', 'https://www.pixiv.net/');
    }

    const requestOptions = {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: myHeaders,
    }

    const fileStream = fs.createWriteStream(absSaveLocation);
    fetch(url, requestOptions)
      .then(res => res.body.pipe(fileStream))
      .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
    fileStream.on('finish', () => {fileStream.close();});
}
```

I've tried a bunch of different libraries, including https, request, fetch, axios and all of them give me the same useless, empty file. It can't be the url as well since it's matched against a regex first before downloading and I've confirmed with countless different urls.

Comment: **node-fetch** has problems with streaming. You might try [**undici**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/undici) instead. See also this [article](https://css-tricks.com/web-streams-everywhere-and-fetch-for-node-js/) for reference.

Comment: Same result unfortunately when just swapping out **node-fetch** for **undici**, thanks for the article though that was an interesting read

Comment: Your code is working for me. I suspect the problem is that you are trying to read the file immediately after calling `downloadURL`, when it's still empty.

Comment: Seems like you're right, if I cut off all the code that runs after **downloadURL** then it does download the entire image and if I only cut off a few lines then only part of the image is downloaded. Isn't `fileStream.on('finish', () => {fileStream.close();});` supposed to make it write to the file until it's finished though?

Answer (score 1):

So I managed to fix this myself in the end by abandonding the whole idea of trying to use a stream to write to the file.

```
const fileStream = fs.createWriteStream(absSaveLocation);
    fetch(url, requestOptions)
      .then(res => res.body.pipe(fileStream))
      .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
    fileStream.on('finish', () => {fileStream.close();});
```

has now become

```
await fetch(url, requestOptions)
      .then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
      .then(buffer => fs.writeFile(absSaveLocation, new Uint8Array(buffer)))
      .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```